# Hahn decomposition for signed measure not unique (Folland)

Tags: real-analysis

In Folland's *Real Analysis*, p.87,

> The decomposition $X = P \cup N$ if $X$ as the disjoint union of a positive set and a negative set is called a **Hahn decomposition** for $\nu$. It is usually not unique ($\nu$-null sets can be transferred from $P$ to $N$ or from $N$ to $P$), but it leads to a canonical representation of $\nu$ as the difference of two positive measures.

It says this decomposition is not unique because $\nu$-null sets can be transferred from $P$ to $N$ and from $N$ to $P$. **What does this mean?** Could anyone provide me with a simple example?

According to the Hahn decomposition theorem, If $P'$ and $N'$ is another such pair, then $P \triangle P'=Q \triangle Q'$ is null for $\nu$. Does not this mean that the decomposition is unique?

Comment: Basically, if $X = P\cup N$ be a decomposition into positive and negative sets. Let $A$ be a null subset of $P$, i.e., $\nu (A) = 0$. Call $P' = P - A$ and $N' = N \cup A$, then $P'$ and $N'$ is also a Hahn decomposition---the decomposition need not be unique.

Comment: Uniqueness can be thought of in more than one sense.  The decomposition is not *strictly* unique in the sense that we can find other decompositions that are not exactly the same.  But what we *can* say is that the decomposition is unique **up to null sets**.  This language just means that **any other decomposition** just differs from the original decomposition by a null set, i.e., the symmetric differences you described are null sets.

Comment: @hrkrshnn Is there always a no empty null subset of $P$?

Comment: @TomRyddle Not sure if I understand your question. For general measures, there can be non-empty null subsets of $P$, However this is not guaranteed. You could just take a discrete set and create a measure on it to create an example.

Comment: @hrkrshnn Aja, in that case, the Hahn decomposition is unique!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Hahn decomposition is unique in the following sense: If $P \cup N$ is a Hahn decomposition of X, then there is another Hahn decomposition $P' \cup N'$ such that $P \triangle P'$ and $N \triangle N'$ are $\nu$-null sets.

Therefore, all Hahn decompositions form a unique equivalence class, similar to $L^p$ spaces being equivalence classes of functions that are almost-everywhere equal.